# Multiple scrolling "windows" in a .NET console app

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Back in the day when I learned programming in school we used Pascal to learn basic concepts.
Now, using C#, I am trying to solve something I thought was basic, but I cannot find a solution.

What I am after is having multiple "windows" in the console that I can write output to and they scroll inside these "virtual windows" or "areas" individually without affecting the others. I also want an input line for commands, but I think that is easier to achieve.

An example could be for instance an IRC chat where I have one area for the chat, one area for the online users and one line for input.

Is there any other way than creating a class that keep track of all the "areas" and do a lot of SetCursorPosition()??? Isn't there anything built-in to .net for this?

Comment: Nothing built in, take a look at this ncurses port: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/monocurses/

Comment: Would be surprised if such a thing was built into .Net... it would uselessly encourage the usage of console for things that are easier and better handled in GUI applications.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll have a look at the ncurses port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the `Console` allows you to set a cursor position, the interface is designed towards being able to "dump and forget" output. Your user interface probably breaks when someone resizes the console.

However in a Windows Forms application, you can easily get an IRC-like interface by:

- Adding a `SplitContainer`, where "panel2" can be used for users
- Adding another `SplitContainer` in "panel1", set `Oritentation` to `Horizontal`
- Add `ListBox` controls to the top and right panels, set `Dock` to `Fill`
- Add a `TextBox` control to the bottom panel, and perhaps a `Button` with its `Text` set to "Send"

This should already be pretty close to where you want to be:

[image]

You can also play around with WPF if you don't like the typical WinForms controls, but the idea is the same.

Comment: OK, I will look at ncurses to see if I can use that. Otherwise I bin the idea of a console app and go with Forms. Thank you!

Comment: I'd always recommend WPF over WinForms for new projects unless you are already familiar with WinForms and need fast results.